# Poisson process distribution how to calculate

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Service calls come to a maintenance counter to a poisson process, and on average, 2.7 calls are recieved per minute. Find the probability that

(a) No more than 4 calls come in any minute

(b) Fewer than 2 calls in any minute

(c) More than 10 calls come in a 5 min period

---

My attempt:

(a) $P(x \leq 4) =\sum_{x=0}^{4} \frac{e^{-2.7}(2.7^x)}{x!} = (\text{ how to calculate?})$

(b) $P(x \leq 1) = \sum_{x=0}^{1} \frac{e^{-2.7}(2.7^x)}{x!} = \text{ how to calculate? }$

(c) $P(x > 10) = 1 - P(x \leq 10) = 1 - \sum_{x=0}^{10} \frac{e^{-(2.7\cdot 5)}(2.7\cdot5)^x}{x!}$

Not sure if I'm doing it right

Comment: Mathematically, I think your answers are correct, so it depends on what your instructor expects (e.g. whether leaving your answer as a summation is ok or if you are expected to give a number by using a calculator/computer).

Comment: Oh, I was wondering if there was like a formula like geometric series, but if not: That's fine.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I don't believe there is a simpler expression for those sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your are doing correct.

Let random variable $X$ denotes number of service calls in $t$ minutes.

Arrival rate of service calls is $\lambda=2.7$ per minute. $X$ has a poisson distribution with parameter $\mu=\lambda t =2.7t$

$$P(X=x)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^x}{x!},\ x=0,1,2,3,4....$$

a)
Probability that there will be no more than $4$ service calls in any minute of time. Here $t=1$ and $\mu=2.7$
$$P(X\le4)=\sum _{ x=0 }^{ 4 }{  e^{-2.7}\frac{(2.7)^x}{x!}}=0.863 $$

b)Here $t=1$, $\mu=2.7$
$$P(X<2)=\sum _{ x=0 }^{ 1 }{ e^{-2.7}\frac{(2.7)^x}{x!}  }=0.2487 $$

c)
Here $t=5$, $\mu=(2.7)(5)=13.5$
$$P(X>10)=1-P(X\le10)$$
$$=1-\sum _{ x=0 }^{ 10 }{e^{-13.5}\frac{(13.5)^x}{x!}}$$
$$P(X>10)=(1-0.2112)=0.789$$